# How do I achieve this look in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

Between the blue and the purple, how do I achieve that transparent look in photoshop?

[image: example]

Comment: some kind of layer effect; i want to say multiply, but i'm neither versed in design nor in photoshop :)

Comment: Draw 3 shapes..... probably by using the Shape tools and various interaction settings, then fill each shape with a different color.

Comment: Hi emi, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a blend mode. Multiply, for example, gives you this:

[image]

You'll want to do as @Scott suggested and create 3 shapes, the intersecting shape being the colour of your choice. For example, create two circle shape layers, then copy both circles into a third layer and then intersect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the two circles to overlap and produce the combined colour in the overlap?

If so I would create two layers, with different coloured circles on each. Then overlap them how you would like, and set the blending mode for the top circle to "multiply" to get the effect you are after.

Example of this is below:

[image: Multiply blending mode]